# What is the file format for Word Starter?

Tags: microsoft-word

What is the format of the file generated by Word Starter? Is it 100% compatible with Word? I search online with "word starter file format spec" but can only find Word document format specifications.

Comment: .Doc and .Docx are the most common but there are more.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get more information about the file formats supported by Word Starter:

The file formats Word Starter can open:

[image]

The file formats Word Starter can generate:
[image]

You will find these files are the same as those supported in Office 2010 and later version of Office.

The files formats supported in Office 2010:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has some but not all the features. It is based on Word 2010.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/word-features-that-are-not-fully-supported-in-word-starter-8467554a-e9d6-4404-a599-f036b29deed8

Comment: It is expected for answers to be more than a link to an external website.  This link does not answer the author’s question.

Comment: As it is based on Word 2010, it will use the Word format (docx) but much reduced feature set.